# is it possible run logdna-agent in USS unix systems

Tags: unix, ibm-cloud, zos, log-analysis

I am trying to feed my server and jar logs into LogDNA log analysis service. My services are all running in mainframe z/OS environment, I have written a simple node js code which could use the LogDNA log ingestion service, that feeds log with REST API. This would be trouble to feed huge log files on a timely basis.
I wanted to see if running the LogDNA agent is feasible in Mainframe z/OS USS unix environment.
[IBM Cloud-Log Analysis](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/log-analysis?topic=log-analysis-config_agent_linux)

Answer (score 0):

Is running the LogDNA agent in Mainframe z/OS USS feasible? Yes, provided you have a binary (executable) that was compiled for z/OS. It seems that IBM does not currently provide one.

I presume you are using *IBM Cloud*. *IBM Log Analysis* is part of *IBM Cloud* as per documentation (your link). You would need to contact IBM and ask if they would provide a *LogDNA Agent* for z/OS.